# Can I define the returned data and html markup in AJAX and use it in another AJAX script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON file on two different pages with different HTML markups and data. I've decided to use two different ajax scripts. I was wondering if it's possible to define the returned data and markups as a function in one of the scripts and call it in another one like this: **([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z9LHB/7/))**

The first script:

```
var markupfunction;
$.ajax({
   url: "www.json.com",
   success: function (data) {
       item_html = parseData(feedformat,data);
   },
    error: function (){}     
});

function parseData(type, data) { 
  switch(type) {
    case 'case1':
     $(data).each(function (index, item) {
       markupfunction = function(){   //****Define the data****//
        item_html += '<h3 class="list">'+item.title+'</h3>';
       }

       markupfunction(); 
     });
    break;
  }

  return item_html;
}
```

The second script

```
$.ajax({
    url: "www.json.com",
    success: function (data) {
        var length = 0;
        var items = data;
        items = items.map(function(item){
            return markupfunction(); //*****Calling the function*******//
        });
        var half = items.length/2;
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            if(i < half)
                $('.main').append(items[i]);
            else
                $('.second').append(items[i]); 
            length++;
        },

    error: function () {}        
});
```

It isn't working. I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Any suggestion?

Comment: do both scripts fire at once? You may have a race condition.

Comment: I think you are confused about where your variables are accessible from. If you define a variable in a function, it's not going to be accessible everywhere. For instance, `item_html` in the 1rst script isn't going to be accessible outside of `markupfunction`.

Comment: @Pow-lan, I've made sure that they won't be fired at once because the first one is in a click function script.

Comment: @Robin, It still isn't working after defining `markupfunction` outside the ajax scripts.

Comment: What you might want to do is look into `handlebars`. You'd have 2 different templates for your 2 pages, then you could easily create the html with the data you're receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed / tweaked your script by changing the markupfunction prototype, ...

```
markupfunction = function(index, item){
    if(arguments.length === 1) {
        item = index;
    }
    var itemMarkup = '<h3 class="list">'+item.title+'</h3>';
    item_html += itemMarkup;
    return itemMarkup;
};
```

The full example in a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z9LHB/11/

**Edit**

Please pay attention to Javascript variable definition scope. A great tutorial about variable scope is available here : http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/ . *Check it out*